# How to speed up packaging Android JNI .so files

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have two JNI .so files for armeabi and armeabi-v7a. Both of them are about 8MB big. I have found that each of them requires 9 secs for APK packaging on my 2 GHz / i7 MacBook Pro with an SSD. I have to wait for 18 secs more for every run even when I just make a simple change in a Java code.

Is there any way to speed up packaging JNI .so files. I am using ADT bundle for my IDE.

Or can I run the app without creating a APK package?

All I need is to speed up the build & run cycle.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: what DSL is used for builds ( ant , gradle ) ?

Comment: I am not sure. I just used ADT bundle as is.

Comment: dont see how you can do anything without diving into the DSL layer... for example 'gradlew --info ... ' on your build and then inspecting all the build steps... http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html   IMO - u should just deal with it.

Comment: Robert, I am using ant for building.

Comment: Years ago I thought java was slow now I enjoy the little waits here and there.  They give me time to think.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.
to rip apart the build you could do following:

1. figure out how to run ant on CLI instead of rely on eclipse
2. run build to be verbose and to log to a file

   ant -debug -Dverbose=true -logfile ../speech-proj-build clean debug
3. rip apart the log to see exactly what is being wasted or repeated unnecessarily in the JNI/android Make steps of your builds
4. in the 'compile' and in the 'javac' steps , find your jni modules and figure out why the make is rebuilding them unnecessary....

Answer (score 0):

For short test cycles, you know exactly if the test device has ARM v6 or ARM v7. Thus, you can reduce the packing time by 50% if you use `APP_ABI=armeabi` or `APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a` in the **Application.mk** while debugging.